# How compute confusion matrix for multiclass classification in Scikit?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, confusion-matrix

I have a multiclass classification task. When I run my script based on the [scikit example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html) as the follows:

```
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=70, max_depth=3, learning_rate=.02))

y_pred = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

I get this error:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 242, in confusion_matrix
    raise ValueError("%s is not supported" % y_type)
ValueError: multilabel-indicator is not supported
```

I tried to pass the `labels=classifier.classes_` to `confusion_matrix()`, but it doesn't help.

y_test and y_pred are as the follow:

```
y_test =
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   ..., 
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])


y_pred = 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   ..., 
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Why do you have `y_pred` and `y_test` as one-hot encoded arrays? What are your original class labels? You should give your code, starting from how you did the transformation of your `y`.

Comment: @VivekKumar I binarized `y_train` and `y_test` as `y_test = label_binarize(y_test, classes=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` for `OneVsRestClassifier()`.

Comment: You should put your original classes (not binarized) into the `confusion_matrix`. You need to reverse transform your `y_pred` to get the original classes from it.

Comment: @VivekKumar Thank you. I used non-binarized version and it solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you need to create the label output array.
Lets say you have 3 classes: 'cat', 'dog', 'house' indexed: 0,1,2 .
And the prediction for 2 samples is: 'dog', 'house'. 
Your output will be:

```
y_pred = [[0, 1, 0],[0, 0, 1]]
```

run y_pred.argmax(1) to get: [1,2]
This array stands for the original label indexes, meaning: 
 ['dog', 'house']

```
num_classes = 3

# from lable to categorial
y_prediction = np.array([1,2]) 
y_categorial = np_utils.to_categorical(y_prediction, num_classes)

# from categorial to lable indexing
y_pred = y_categorial.argmax(1)
```

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

```
y_test_non_category = [ np.argmax(t) for t in y_test ]
y_predict_non_category = [ np.argmax(t) for t in y_predict ]

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test_non_category, y_predict_non_category)
```

where `y_test` and `y_predict` are categorical variables like one-hot vectors.

Answer (score 0):

I just subtracted the outputs `y_test` matrix from the prediction `y_pred` matrix while keeping the categorical format. In case of `-1`, I assumed a false negative while in case of `1`, a false positive.

Next:

```
if output_matrix[i,j] == 1 and predictions_matrix[i,j] == 1:  
    produced_matrix[i,j] = 2
```

Ending up with the following notation:

- -1: false negative
- 1: false positive
- 0: true negative
- 2: true positive

Finally, be performing some naive counting you can produce any confusion metric.